# Add computable column to multi-table select clause with eager_load in Ruby on Rails Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a query with a lot of joins and I'm `eager_load`ing some of associations at the time. And I need to compute some value as attribute of one of models.

So, I'm trying this code:

```
ServiceObject
  .joins([{service_days: :ou}, :address])
  .eager_load(:address, :service_days)
  .where(ous: {id: OU.where(sector_code: 5)})
  .select('SDO_CONTAINS(ous.service_area_shape, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, sdo_point_type(addresses.lat, addresses.lng, NULL), NULL, NULL) ) AS in_zone')
```

Where SQL function call in `select` operates data from associated `addresses` and `ous` tables.

I'm getting next SQL (so my `in_zone` column getting calculated and returned as first column before other columns for all `eager_load`ed models):

```
SELECT SDO_CONTAINS(ous.service_area_shape, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, sdo_point_type(addresses.lat, addresses.lng, NULL), NULL, NULL) ) AS in_zone, "SERVICE_OBJECTS"."ID" AS t0_r0, "SERVICE_OBJECTS"."TYPE" AS t0_r1, <omitted for brevity> AS t2_r36 FROM "SERVICE_OBJECTS" INNER JOIN "SERVICE_DAYS" ON "SERVICE_DAYS"."SERVICE_OBJECT_ID" = "SERVICE_OBJECTS"."ID" INNER JOIN "OUS" ON "OUS"."ID" = "SERVICE_DAYS"."OU_ID" INNER JOIN "ADDRESSES" ON "ADDRESSES"."ID" = "SERVICE_OBJECTS"."ADDRESS_ID" WHERE "OUS"."ID" IN (SELECT "OUS"."ID" FROM "OUS" WHERE "OUS"."SECTOR_CODE" = :a1)  [["sector_code", "5"]]
```

But it seems like that `in_zone` isn't accessible from either model used in query.

**I need to have calculated `in_zone` as attribute of `ServiceObject` model object, how I can accomplish that?**

Ruby on Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.3.0, oracle_enhanced adapter 1.6.7, Oracle 12.1

Comment: So, your query looks properly, executes properly, returns proper values in this alias column, but these values don't end up in your model instances?

Comment: assuming you assigned a result of that query to some variable (e.g. `objects`), what actually is the result of calling `objects.first.in_zone`?

Comment: @MladenJablanović yes, exactly.
@twonegatives, I'm getting error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'in_zone' for #<ServiceObject::Atm:0x0000000a6d24a0>`

Comment: Where does the `Atm` come from? I would expect the object to be of `ServiceObject` class.

Comment: This is just polymorphic (STI) model (`class ServiceObject::Atm < ServiceObject` with `type` column)

Comment: The steps I would try in your place: 1) simplify your query, to easier pinpoint the step where the error occurs 2) scatter debug output all over the ActiveRecord codepath and see which fields get to the model constructor.

Comment: Dumb question: did you define an attr_accessor for the property in the model? As it is not an actual column, AR will not know of it (it gets the columns from schema.rb)

Comment: Actually it seems this is a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15185)

Comment: @JuliaWill: No it's not real column and I didn't define attr_accessor or anything. Thank you for link to issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That monkey patch helped @Envek:

```
module ActiveRecord
  Base.send :attr_accessor, :_row_

  module Associations
    class JoinDependency
      JoinBase && class JoinPart
        def instantiate_with_row(row, *args)
          instantiate_without_row(row, *args).tap { |i| i._row_ = row }
        end; alias_method_chain :instantiate, :row
      end
    end
  end
end
```

then it is possible to do:

```
ServiceObject
  .joins([{service_days: :ou}, :address])
  .eager_load(:address, :service_days)
  .where(ous: {id: OU.where(sector_code: 5)})
  .select('SDO_CONTAINS(ous.service_area_shape, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, sdo_point_type(addresses.lat, addresses.lng, NULL), NULL, NULL) ) AS in_zone')
  .first
  ._row_['in_zone']
```

Comment: Yes, that's me :-)

Comment: This didn't work on rails6. The error message is `undefined method alias_method_chain for ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinPart:Class`. Does anyone know the new version?

Answer (score 13):

I have successfully replicated your issue and it turns out that **this is a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15185) in Rails**. The problem is that when using `eager_load`, Rails maps the columns of all eager-loaded tables into **[table and column aliases](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb#L123)** in the form of `t0_r0`, `t0_r1`, etc... (you can see these in the SQL that you pasted in the question). And while doing that, it simply ignores the custom columns in the `select`, probably because it cannot determine which eager-loaded table it should attribute the custom column to. It is sad that this issue is open for more than 2 years now...

Nevertheless I think I found a workaround. It seems that if you don't eager load the tables but **manually join them** (with `joins`), you can **as well include them** (with `includes`) and the custom columns will be returned as **there will be no column aliasing taking place**. The point is that you must not use associations in the `joins` clauses but you have to specify the joins yourself. Also note that you must specify all columns from the main table in the select manually too (see the `service_objects.*` in the select).

Try the following approach:

```
ServiceObject
  .joins('INNER JOIN "SERVICE_DAYS" ON "SERVICE_DAYS"."SERVICE_OBJECT_ID" = "SERVICE_OBJECTS"."ID"')
  .joins('INNER JOIN "OUS" ON "OUS"."ID" = "SERVICE_DAYS"."OU_ID"')
  .joins('INNER JOIN "ADDRESSES" ON "ADDRESSES"."ID" = "SERVICE_OBJECTS"."ADDRESS_ID"')
  .includes(:service_days, :address)
  .where(ous: {id: OU.where(sector_code: 5)})
  .select('service_objects.*, SDO_CONTAINS(ous.service_area_shape, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, sdo_point_type(addresses.lat, addresses.lng, NULL), NULL, NULL) ) AS in_zone')
```

The computation in the select should still work as the related tables are `join`ed together but there should be no column aliasing present.

Of course this approach means that you'll get three queries instead of just one but unless you return a huge amount of records, the following two queries run by the `includes` clause should be very fast as they simply load the relevant records using foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you! I want to avoid three queries as Oracle have limit of 1000 identifiers in one query and when `service_object` has_many `service_days` it's relatively easy to hit it.

Comment: I don't think the limit for `IN` will be a problem as it is the main record ids (service_object ids) that is put into the `IN (...)` in both `belongs_to` and `has_many` cases.

Comment: However, I didn't notice that **`service_objects` have many `service_days`** (I presumed only `belongs_to` assoc). This complicates things: 1) you'd have to add `distinct` to the select so that only a single `service_day` is returned (and not repeated by the joins). 2) What really baffles me is - how can you then calculate the `in_zone` and expect it to be returned with `service_object` **while it depends on a `has_many` association** (service_days → ou)?? I guess the `in_zone` might be different for each `service_day` then, i.e. not the same for a `service_object`. Or am I getting st. wrong?

Comment: Uh, yes, it complicates: 1. `distinct` ruins performance. and 2. you can't use `distinct` in Oracle for large text fields (`CLOB`s). Maybe it worth to introduce N queries just to calculate this `in_zone` when rendering paginated response. Service Days are belongs to OU, but Service Object may have many Service Days that are belonging to different OU, so that's why `where(ous: {id: OU.where(sector_code: 5)})` is there. Thank you for good advices, I'll play with different variants shortly.

Comment: If that `where(ous...)` actually limits the joined `service_days` down to **1 `service_day` per `service_object`**, then there is no need for `distinct` and the query in the answer should IMO work. As I commented above, there won't be more IDs searched in the `IN` clause in the consequent 2 queries than the number of returned `service_object`s, so if you use paging, all should be fine.

Comment: No, there are many `service_days` per `service_object` in one `OU`, so your query without `DISTINCT` returns duplicated `ServiceObject` objects. In my particular case `DISTINCT` works as there are no `CLOB`s in that table. Thank you!